# Why is this page incompatible with mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css

I'm working on a hybrid app and created the following page: http://api.babelmatch.com:3000/learn (code pasted below in case this URL is offline in the future).  It loads fine when I test it in Chrome and Safari on my Mac.  However, when I visit the same URL with an iPhone (Safari and Chrome) or Samsung Galaxy S2 (Chrome) the page does not load.  Instead the browser loads a blank white page.

Am I using some unsupported javascript or CSS that could be causing this problem?

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #content {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #row1 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
        }
        #row2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50%;
        }
        #q1 {
            float:left;
            background-color:red;
        }
        #q2 {
            float:left;
            background-color:yellow;
        }
        #q3 {
            float:left;
            background-color:blue;
        }
        #q4 {
            float:left;
            background-color:green;
        }
        #leftmargin {
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            background-color:orange;
        }
        #rightmargin {
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
            background-color:purple;
        }
        #imageGrid {
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }
        .qImage {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .circle {
            border-radius: 1000px;
            background-color: rgb(0, 162, 232);
            z-index:100;
            top: 50% left: 50% position: fixed;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="leftmargin"></div>
        <div id="imageGrid">
            <div id="row1">
                <div id="q1">
                    <img id="q1Image" data-bind="attr:{src: q1ImagePath}" class="qImage" />
                </div>
                <div id="q2">
                    <img id="q2Image" data-bind="attr:{src: q2ImagePath}" class="qImage" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="row2">
                <div id="q3">
                    <img id="q3Image" data-bind="attr:{src: q3ImagePath}" class="qImage" />
                </div>
                <div id="q4">
                    <img id="q1Image" data-bind="attr:{src: q4ImagePath}" class="qImage" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightmargin"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Set up the layout
        var viewportWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            viewportHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
            q1 = document.getElementById("q1"),
            leftmargin = document.getElementById("leftmargin"),
            rightmargin = document.getElementById("rightmargin"),
            squareSize;
        if (viewportHeight <= viewportWidth) {
            //landscape
            squareSize = viewportHeight / 2;
            leftmargin.style.width = (viewportWidth - squareSize - squareSize) / 2;
            rightmargin.style.width = leftmargin.style.width;
        } else {
            //portrait
            squareSize = viewportWidth / 2;
            leftmargin.style.display = none;
            rightmargin.style.display = none;
        }
        q1.style.height = squareSize;
        q1.style.width = squareSize;
        q2.style.height = squareSize;
        q2.style.width = squareSize;
        q3.style.height = squareSize;
        q3.style.width = squareSize;
        q4.style.height = squareSize;
        q4.style.width = squareSize;
        //style the circle play button
        function upd() {
            var h = $("body").height();
            $(".circle").height(h / 5);
            $(".circle").width(h / 5);
        }
        upd();
        window.onresize = upd;
        //UI control logic
        //knockoutjs stuff
        function GridViewModel() {
            //data
            var self = this;
            self.q1ImagePath = ko.observable();
            self.q2ImagePath = ko.observable();
            self.q3ImagePath = ko.observable();
            self.q4ImagePath = ko.observable();

            // Load initial state from server, convert it to Grid instances, then populate self.tasks
            $.getJSON("http://api.babelmatch.com:3000/image?language=Cantonese&count=4", function (allData) {
                var baseUrl = "http://d22a3fhj26r1b.cloudfront.net/";
                self.q1ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[0].imageFileName);
                self.q2ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[1].imageFileName)
                self.q3ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[2].imageFileName)
                self.q4ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[3].imageFileName)
            });

            //operations

            self.refreshImages = function () {
                $.getJSON("http://api.babelmatch.com:3000/image?language=Cantonese&count=" + count, function (allData) {
                    var baseUrl = "http://d22a3fhj26r1b.cloudfront.net/";
                    self.q1ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[0].imageFileName);
                    self.q2ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[1].imageFileName)
                    self.q3ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[2].imageFileName)
                    self.q4ImagePath(baseUrl + allData[3].imageFileName)
                });
            }


        }
        ko.applyBindings(new GridViewModel());
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page has no `doctype`, which forces it into quirks mode in browsers. jQuery does not support quirks mode and you will run into unexpected behavior

Run page through w3c validator service and get it clean

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.babelmatch.com%3A3000%2Flearn

Answer (score 0):

`height:100%` is generally not supported very well by most browsers.
http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/